# updating runtime value of aws lambda function module into nodejs16

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-sdk-nodejs

I need to update the runtime value from nodejs14 to nodejs16. When I update the runtime of my terraform runtime value into nodejs16.x its giving the following error.

expected runtime to be one of [nodejs nodejs4.3 nodejs6.10 nodejs8.10 nodejs10.x nodejs12.x nodejs14.x java8 java8.al2 java11 python2.7 python3.6 python3.7 python3.8 python3.9 dotnetcore1.0 dotnetcore2.0 dotnetcore2.1 dotnetcore3.1 nodejs4.3-edge go1.x ruby2.5 ruby2.7 provided provided.al2], got nodejs16.x

Comment: Valid runtimes are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateFunction.html#SSS-CreateFunction-request-Runtime). Back-level Terraform maybe? Which AWS region?

Comment: Some runtimes are region locked, and only available in certain regions. Check to see if nodejs16 is available in your region. If its not, you may need to update Terraform or see if Terraform has a patch for this as it may be a type checking done there.

Answer (score 4):

[nodejs16.x support has been added](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/24714) to v3.75.2 and v4.x AWS provider versions

Check your AWS provider version in your terraform code and update it.

Comment: my aws provider version is 4.1.0 still the same error!

Comment: [v3.75.2](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/releases/tag/v3.75.2) release date was May 20th 2022, but [v4.15.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/releases/tag/v4.15.0) release date was May 19th just one day before. I was running into the same issue and updating to v4.16.0 (released May 27th) fixed it for me

Comment: I received this error when trying to set the engine to nodejs18.x on aws provider v4.30.0.  I fixed it when I upgraded to v4.65.0.

Answer (score 3):

changed the runtime value into nodejs16.x , aws cli new version wasn't installed, upgraded that. then I used aws provider version value as 4.15.0, this will give you error when we run terraform init. then you have to give command 'terraform init -upgrade. then the aws provider will be upgraded to the required one, this time the error was gone and nodejs16.x is valid

Comment: 'terraform init -upgrade' was really helpful thanks